# A typo in specifying a chart on a set

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In the textbook that I am currently reading, I faced a typo which I have specified in blue. The text goes as follows:

Assume that $W\subset\mathbb R^m$ and $V\subset\mathbb R^n$ are open sets, that $M$ is a subset of the product $\mathbb R^m \times \mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^{m+n},$ and $f:W\to V$ is a map whose graph is a subset of $M,$ i.e.
$$\operatorname{graph}(f):=\{(x,y)\in W\times V|x\in W, y=f(x)\}\subset M.$$
Let $\color{blue} {U = (W \cap V)\cap \operatorname{graph}(f)}$ and let $\phi(x,y) = x$ be the projection of $U$ onto $W.$ Then the pair $(\phi,U)$ is a chart on $M.$

The blue part must be a typo, but I could not correct this as my correction would make this part a trivial expression. What is the correction?

(By definition, a chart on a set $M$ is a bijection from a subset of $M$ onto an open set in a Euclidean space.)

Comment: Perhaps $W\times V$?

Comment: But the graph is its subset so it would be a redundant expression @MatthewLeingang

Comment: True.  I'm not sure how else to combine an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and obtain a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$.

Comment: What is the textbook?

Comment: @Aweygan in fact it may not be a textbook, and it is maybe a preliminary version of an upcoming book, introduction to differential geometry by Robbin and Salamon https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf

Comment: @Aweygan in the very beginning, page 4, example 1.2.3

Comment: I think if the map is assumed to be continuous and the chart domain is taken to be the graph itself, then the problem is solved, or did the authors probably have another chart in their mind?

Comment: Even if we assume it is $W\times V$, which seems to be the most likely correction, it looks to me like the whole example is wrong, or at least missing information.  The function $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(0,\ldots,0,x_n)$ has graph a subset of $\mathbb R^{2n}$, but the map $\phi$ discussed does not produce a chart of $M=\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: I think I found out what the authors had in their mind. The chart is $(Q\times V)\cap graph(f)$ where $Q$ is an open set in the domain $W$. @Aweygan